# simple signal code in C, some confusion

Tags: c, linux, output, signals

So here is some simple signal code in C. I have just a few questions on the concept behind this code. I don't have Linux on my computer, so please consider explaining the concept behind this code to me; I really appreciate this!

1. What does the array `int list[]` store? Is it just number of handler?
2. What does the `list[i] = sig` after `sleep()` mean?
3. What should be the output for this code; I don't have Linux on my computer.
4. What does the function `void Dump()` do exactly?

Here is the code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int list[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
void handler(int sig) {
  int i = 0;
  while(list[i]!=0) { i++;}
  sleep(10);
  list[i] = sig;
  write(1, "Outta here\n" , 11) ;
}
void dump(int sig) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    printf("list[%d]=%d\n" , i, list[i]);
  }
  _exit(0);
}
main( ) {
  signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
  signal(SIGUSR2, handler) ;
  signal(SIGTERM, dump);
  printf("Handlers installed\n");
  while (1);
}
```

Comment: You should install Linux on your computer (perhaps inside some VM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's an array storing the last 10 signals handled, the value is the number that corresponds to the signal itself
2. It's adding the signal number to the array, at the next free index
3. The output should be a list of handled signals, the numeric value corresponding to one of either `SIGUSR1`,  `SIGUSR2`, or `0`, once the `SIGTERM` signal is received by the program.
4. The `dump()` function outputs all signal values stored in the list